# What is the best way to move the context of a git repo?

Tags: git, jekyll, github-pages

I currently have a git repo for a Jekyll blog that publishes to GitHub Pages. When I set this up initially I initialized git at the root of the blog directory. This means I'm committing and pushing all the Jekyll source files rather than only the static rendered content. Basically, I want to push from

```
$~/writing/_site/
```

as the root rather than what I'm currently pushing from

```
$~/writing/
```

I would like to start pushing to the remote repo *just* the static content, leaving all the source files only on my local machine. I've considered creating a local branch and changing things but I don't think that achieves my result. It's not that I'm changing the content itself, but rather pushing a child directory rather than a parent directory.

I assume I could issue

```
$ git push --force
```

from the parent directory and then initialize a repo at the child directory and push from *it*, but that seems like a crude ignorance at play.

I could `git-push --force`, copy the Jekyll source to another untracked directory, and then create a branch and `git-rm` all the source and `git-mv` the content from the child directory into the parent directory but this also feels like oil painting with a piece of bread.

Comment: You do have to do something very different, because `git push` pushes *commits*, not files. A commit is a complete source tree snapshot. There's no way to push a partial snapshot (it's not a commit and `git push` pushes commits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to continue to have version control for the source code of your site, to do what you want, you'll need two completely separate Git repositories. One to store the source code, and another one to store the static contents that are generated by Jekyll in the `_site` folder.

- **repoA** - Full Jekyll source code
- **repoB** - Just the static content

The workflow would be something like this:

1. Make changes to repo**A** (e.g. write a new post)
2. Commit changes on repo**A**
3. Run `jekyll` to build your website (generates `_site`)
4. (Optionally) push the changes somewhere, usually private
5. Delete all files and folders on repo**B**
6. Move all contents from repo**A**`\_site` to repo**B**`\`
7. Commit changes on repo**B**
8. Push changes in repo**B** to GitHub pages

You'll probably want to automate steps `5` to `8` as they are boring and repetitive. For that there are a myriad of tools you can use, such as [Rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake), [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com), [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com), etc.

If you go with Rake, you may also want to take a look at [jekyll-rakefile](https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-rakefile).

Comment: This is, after some reading, how I’d set it up with Pelican or any other generator, too. I realized with the help of commentary here I was confusing conceptual models.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the other site a `git` repository, and don't use `git` to transfer the static content.  As torek's comment states, `git` communicates everything that is checked in (and only what is checked in).  Instead, after building, you should use another tool such as `scp` or `rsync` to transfer the content.

Comment: I’m using GitHub Pages for hosting and as I assume git is the only method of moving files.

Comment: Ah, well that's relevant information that should have been in the question; I didn't see the tag.  Yeah, the other answer works well then.